# control battery behavior in omnet++/inet

Tags: c++, battery, omnet++, inet

i need to write a battery model that is able to discharge and charge at specified times in a simulated wireless sensor network in omnet++ using inet modules.

as far as i got i did understand that i need to build an `IBattery` implementation to provide battery specifications and maybe recharging capabilities and some other module/way to begin discharging and charging periods.

one idea was to implement the `IPowerControl` interface but it does not seem to have control over the type of event (e.g. charging or discharging)

what should i look for? i am a bit overwhelmed by inet source code dimension and got lost...

Comment: this might be useful: https://omnetpp.org/component/content/article?id=3647:energyframework

Comment: Are you using INET 3? https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/tree/master/src/inet/power or INET 2 https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/tree/v2.x/src/battery ? 
INET 3 has a considerably more sophisticated energy management infrastructure.

Comment: @Rudi Nope,I need to work with a specific version of inet 2 (a slightly modified 2.2 version, with custom routing protocols)